# Stored Procedure Dependency

Tags: sql-server

I have a very large SQL Server instance with many databases that are interrelated.

We use stored procedures for all data access and these stored procedures make use of synonyms and views to access the data.

I'm looking for a way to 'parse' the stored procedure into its root components - ie if the stored procedure uses a synonym that maps to table 'x' in DB 'y' then I would like it to show me that. Same if it uses views. Many of the stored procedures have multiple synonyms and views in use.

Bonus points if it could also show the actual column in addition to the database and table.

I have found some references to parts of this - for example

```
SELECT 
    referenced_schema_name, referenced_entity_name,
    referenced_minor_name
FROM 
    sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.usp_get_Account_Search', 'OBJECT')
GO
```

will show my the synonyms/views in use but doesn't go any deeper.

Answer (score 0):

something like this needs to help

```
SELECT
  s.name,
  s.type,
  s.type_desc,
  base_object_name,
  o.type ref_type,
  o.type_desc ref_type_Desc,
  referenced_entity_name,
  COALESCE(PARSENAME(base_object_name,2),SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID())) schemaName
FROM sys.synonyms s
inner join sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.mytestfnc','OBJECT') ob
  on  ob.referenced_id = s.object_id
inner join sys.objects o 
  on o.name = PARSENAME(base_object_name,1)
```